# passing multiple values for same id through php

Tags: php, json

I want to pass multiple values through my `url` as below.

> http://example.com/shopping_cart_json_api.php?uid=5710,55

I have created the `php` encode file as below however I am unable to get proper result out.

```
<?php
require('adminpanel/includes/application_top.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $id = explode(",", $_GET["uid"]);
    $sth = mysql_query(" SELECT drug_medicines.fld_id,   
        drug_medicines.fld_image, drug_medicines.ld_product_name,
        drug_medicines.fld_best_price,drug_cart.ld_userid,
        drug_cart.fld_qunty, drug_cart.fld_totalprice
        FROM drug_medicines
        INNER JOIN drug_cart
        ON drug_medicines.fld_id=drug_cart.fld_productid 
        WHERE fld_userid='" . $id . "' ||'" . $id . "'");
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code, is vulnerable to SQL Injections and you also used the outdated version of MySQL query's.. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. [Read how to use MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Please use mysqli or pdo if you dont want to make your database vulnerable

Comment: OP, I removed the URL to your site and replaced it with a dummy value for security reasons. Change it back if you insist on making it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` in mysql query.

```
<?php
require('adminpanel/includes/application_top.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $id = explode(",", $_GET["uid"]);
    $sth = mysql_query("
            SELECT 
                drug_medicines.fld_id,   
                drug_medicines.fld_image, drug_medicines.ld_product_name,
                drug_medicines.fld_best_price,drug_cart.ld_userid,
                drug_cart.fld_qunty, drug_cart.fld_totalprice
            FROM 
                drug_medicines
            INNER JOIN 
                drug_cart
            ON 
                drug_medicines.fld_id=drug_cart.fld_productid 
            WHERE 
                fld_userid IN (" . $_GET["uid"] . ")");
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome :) Feel free to accept the answer. @DeepakSingh

Answer (score 3):

Format should be like this.

`WHERE fld_userid='".$id[0]."' OR fld_userid= '".$id[1]."'");`

For values more than 2 use

`WHERE fld_userid IN (" . implode(',', $id) . ")"`

Comment: should be `WHERE fld_userid='".$id[0]."' OR fld_userid= '".$id[1]."'");`

Comment: or IN (urfusion's answer)

Comment: according to your approach user might need to put these values in loop or should fix the number of values he is passing in the url. So it is just a solution of current scenario not a perfect answer.

Comment: @DeepakSingh please accept the above answer if it correctly answered your question

Answer (score 2):

As per your `URL` you might have more values in future so you should use `IN` function of `mysql`

```
fld_userid IN ($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IN` for more flexibility.

```
"... WHERE fld_userid IN (" . implode(',', $id) . ")"
```

Which will output:

```
"... WHERE fld_userid IN (5710,55)"
```

Comment: got your implode params backwards

Comment: Sorry, haven't used PHP in a while :) fixed, thank you